# Dupont jump wire in order to replace 20 pin cable

Tags: connector, cables, 12v, jumper

[image]
Hello, I bought a mp5 player for my car and I didn't find the 20 pin cable for this player. My question is if I could replace it by Dupont jumper wires as the picture shows

Comment: I doubt those jumper wires have an automotive-grade vibration spec ... I'd be concerned that they'd fall out over time.

Comment: It looks like an old floppy ribbon cable at this end.

Comment: Is there such a thing as mp5?

Comment: i think that an MP5 is a weapon

Comment: MP5 is a format, apparently. Also a sub machine gun. The most cost effective weapon in Counterstrike, but I prefer the finality of the equally economic pump shotgun.

Answer (score 1):

As said by brhans, the Dupont cable is most likely going to fall out due to the vibrations made by a car. One thing you could use to mitigate this problem is to install a proper cable connector. One of these could work: [Connector](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00270MLJO)

If you're not willing to use a proper cable connector though, you could always hot glue the Dupont connectors to wherever they need to go. This can give you some protection from vibrations but may not be the best solution.